# My new Galaxy S8+ is set to Norwegian Language

Tags: search

Swith to Norwegian as Country/Area for Bing.  It defaults to Chine

When trying to use Bing as a search engine, it comes up with chinese, but I can't see how to change it to norwegian or any other language.  I can choose Norwegian, but can't save the setting

Comment: What do you really want to accomplish?

Comment: Can you not switch to Norwegian and save the setting at http://www.bing.com/settings.aspx ?

Comment: 1. I want to use Bing as the search engine instead of Google
2. The language on the phone is Norwegian.
3. When loading Bing using Opera as browser it starts with chinese
4. I sekect Norway as Land/area
5. I can't find where to save the new setting so it remains as chinese

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a VPN of some sort? Plus did you get right domain extension? You might me using one of the Chinese domain extensions... or you could just change the language....